# c++ append one character from a string to another string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test("hello world ");
    std::string label("label test");
    test.append(&label[3]);    //----- #1
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

for the above code, what I expected is "hello world e", but in fact, its output is "hello world el test". It append all the characters after position 3 to my string `test`.

At the position #1, if I don't put the & sign, there will be compilation error:

```
str_append.cpp:10:10: error: no matching member function for call to 'append'
    test.append(label[3]);
    ~~~~~^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1516:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
    basic_string& append(const value_type* __s);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1513:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'value_type' (aka 'char') to 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' for 1st argument
    basic_string& append(const basic_string& __str);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1525:9: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 1 was provided
        append(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1532:9: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 1 was provided
        append(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1515:19: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 1 was provided
    basic_string& append(const value_type* __s, size_type __n);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1517:19: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2
      arguments, but 1 was provided
    basic_string& append(size_type __n, value_type __c);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1514:19: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 2
      arguments, but 1 was provided
    basic_string& append(const basic_string& __str, size_type __pos, size_type __n=npos);
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

The only way i can solve this is to change the #1 line to :

```
test += label[3];
```

So, I want to know what the logic behind this? Can't `label[3]` return a single character? why it fails when i just use `test.append(label[3]);`. And why `test += label[3];` succeeds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yet another "I didn't read the documentation" question. What is wrong with the world? *downvotes and cries*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't appending a character; you're appending a C-string. That C-string is provided by the pointer `&label[3]`, which points to the following data: `{'e','l',' ','t','e','s','t','\0'}`.

To append a character you'd just pass `label[3]` itself. However, to do this you need to use `basic_string& append(size_type count, CharT ch)`, or its convenient equivalent (when `count==1`), `void push_back(CharT ch)`.

The `operator+=` is functionally analogous to `push_back`, which is why it worked when you tried it.

So:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test("hello world ");
    std::string label("label test");

    test.append(1, label[3]);  // or...
    test.push_back(label[3]);  // or...
    test += label[3];

    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

In brief, *read the documentation* to find out what members `std::string` has, and how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no `std::basic_string::append()` overload that takes a single character. See for yourself [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append).

Basically, `std::basic_string::append()` is not designed to add a single character to the back of a string, but characters. The [`std::basic_string::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) is designed for this purpose instead. Or you may just use [`operator +`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which is applicable to both a single character and characters.

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), the descriptions for each function are (emphasis mine):

- `append()`: Appends **characters** to the end
- `push_back()`: Appends **a character** to the end
- `operator +`: Concatenates two strings or a string and a char

Answer (score 0):

`label[3]` will return a single character (structly speaking, a reference of it), but unfortunately `std::string` doesn't have a function `append` that takes one character.

`test.append('a');` also fails.

`std::string` has `operator+=` that takes one character, so `test += label[3];` succeeds.

Comment: Actually, it is `operator +`. `std::basic_string` does not have a `operator +=` overload.

Comment: @Lingxi [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says that `basic_string` has `basic_string& operator+=(charT c);` (21.4.6.1 basic_string::operator+=)